# How to install Tkinter module with python 2.7.5 in Redhat linux 7?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have Python 2.7.5 in rhel-7x. I have tried to import Tkinter but i got a error as below

```
`Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16) 
 [GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import Tkinter
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        ImportError: No module named Tkinter`
```

Can you help me to install Tkinter module in rhel-7x with python version 2.7.5 ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

In which redhat are you ? Enterprise, fedora, centOs ?

```
yum install tkinter
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see rhel

Comment: Red hat version 7.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the optional rpm repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo`.

You may find the section like below in the file, and set `enable=1`.

```
 [rhel-7-workstation-optional-rpms]
  ...
 enabled = 1
```

After enabling the optional, the command `sudo yum install tkinter` may work as it does for me.